# JasperReports' iReport - generating a grand total

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a variable datatype set up in the group footer band that generates a subtotal for the counts in each group in my report. Works great. 
I would like a grand total to generate on the last page of my report, simply summing up the subtotal values. This has been harder to figure out.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use two variables with different ***`resetType`*** - for calculating sum in group (with *`resetType="Group" resetGroup="groupName" calculation="Sum"`* properties) and for calculating total sum for whole report (with *`resetType="Report" calculation="Sum"`* properties).

The sample (`jrxml` file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="grand_total_sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT DOCUMENTID, POSITIONNO, PRODUCTID, QUANTITY FROM POSITIONS WHERE PRODUCTID < 10 AND POSITIONNO > 18 ORDER BY POSITIONNO]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DOCUMENTID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="POSITIONNO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PRODUCTID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="QUANTITY" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="quantitySumInGroup" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="positionNoGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QUANTITY}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="quantityTotalSum" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{QUANTITY}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="positionNoGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{POSITIONNO}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="400" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Position no: " + $F{POSITIONNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="400" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Sum in group: " + $V{quantitySumInGroup}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCUMENTID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCTID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{QUANTITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="400" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total sum: " + $V{quantityTotalSum}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: The result in iReport preview]

Answer (score -1):

Just create a new variable and in the variable expression add up all of the subtotals using their variable name

for instance:

```
$V{subtotal1}+$V{subtotal2}+$V{subtotal3}
```

After that, throw it in the 'summary' band and in the report properties check the box that says "summary on new page". That way it'll be on the last page of your report.

Comment: I think this answer is in the right area, but my subtotal field is a single field which only shows one variable name. Incrementing the variable name in the expression editor like above does not work.

Comment: This will not work since each subtotal is actually the same variable just being reset for each group.