# How to create a running total over pages?

Tags: sum, jasper-reports, accumulate

What I want to achieve is a cumulative subtotal on the bottom of each page.

On the first page the total for that page of a column (let’s call this column A ) would be displayed. On the second page the total of page one and page two for column A is displayed and so on until the last page on which the overall total is shown.

Can someone provide me with a way to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicates: [JasperReports' iReport - generating a grand total](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9671761/876298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create accumulate sum's over page, columns, group's you can used the [`evaluationTime`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html) attribute on the `textField`

**The setup is:**

Create a variabile that calculates the value (in your case a sum on a field)

```
<variable name="mySumVar" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{myFieldToSum}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

> Important do not set `resetType` on variabile, this would reset the value accordingly and instead we want a accumulative value

Now as report is running (detail band iterating) this variabile will have the current value (sum of fields iterated).

To display an accumulative value relative to page, group etc, we use a textField with relative evaluationTime (if on bottom of page for example in `columnFooter` if on top you can use `columnHeader`).

In your case you want accumulative on page so you set `evaluationTime="Page"`

```
<textField evaluationTime="Page">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6736d772-987d-4ad0-af4c-9d19e631eb07"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{mySumVar}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```